# Filter data based on sum of two fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have following Django model

```
class OfflineExamResult(models.Model):
  """ Model to store result of offline exam """
  batch = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
  date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
  full_marks = models.IntegerField(default=80)
  rank = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
  uid1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
  uid2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
  marks = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

The students in my class have been allotted a roll number which is sum (string sum) of uid1 and uid2. I want to create a search field so that students enter their roll number and get their result which will happen, only if I am able to filter objects after comparing roll number to sum of uid1 and uid2.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **[F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)** with `annotation()`.

```
from django.db.models import F

students = OfflineExamResult.objects.annotate(roll=F('uid1') + F('uid2')).\
filter(roll=given_roll_number)
```

Comment: The code is running without any error, it just not returning any result at all.

Comment: Do you have data in db, and have you tried printing the `students` object.

Comment: Yes, I do have data in db, have tried the code in Django shell, like I told you - it return an empty list.

Comment: The code should work, just try adding some more data and try.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `uid1` and `uid2` are **CharFields** you need to use [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) database function if you want to perform arithmetical operations among CharFields.

This should work:

```
from django.db.models import F, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

students = OfflineExamResult.objects.annotate(uid1_int=Cast('uid1', IntegerField()), uid2_int=Cast('uid2', IntegerField())).annotate(roll=F('uid1_int') + F('uid2_int')).filter(roll=roll_number)
```

P.S.

I used `IntegerField` field in my example but if you have decimal numbers in the database you should use `FloatField` instead.